# how to ignore a folder in a given location - mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How can ignore the folder called `build` in the root of my project, but not ignore a folder called `build` anywhere else?

i.e.

```
/myprog/.hgignore
/myproj/make
/myproj/build <-ignore this
/myproj/lib/somelib/build <- dont ignore this
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the regexp syntax as per [doc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html).
Your .hgignore should then contain

```
syntax: regexp
^build
```

Comment: You can also use `glob` syntax if you specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.hgignore` file. You will want to add a line

`/myproj/build`

Comment: I don't think that does it.  Mercurial uses relatives paths when checking .hgignore and '/' isn't considered anchored to the repository root.  In regexp mode you can use '^' to anchor as @tigrisc suggested, but in glob mode there's no way to anchor

Comment: Though in this case it might not matter, unless he has `/myproj/lib/myproj/build` (ie. /myproj twice)